# Is there an easy way to indent all the linguistic examples with expex?

Tags: linguistics, expex

Like this one:

[image]

I browse through the expex document but couldn't find these infos.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The picture you've posted has example `(49)` indented. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant - is there a way of getting the indentation for all of the examples in a whole document without individually setting (just trying to show one example in the post)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation of examples in ExPex is set by the `numoffset` key.  You can set it globally by using `\lingset`, for example:

```
\lingset{numoffset=.5cm}
```

To set it to match the indents on paragraphs, use:

```
\lingset{numoffset=\parindent}
```